# Check if row exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Given database schema:

```
Part( P#, PName, Producer, Year, Price)
Customer( C#, CName, Province)
Supply(S#, P#, C#, Quantity, Amount, Date)
```

How would I create a query to list names and provinces of the customers who did not buy any Apple products?

I have:

```
SELECT 
   b.cname, 
   b.province
FROM 
   part c, 
   customer b, 
   supply a
WHERE 
   c.PID = a.PID
   AND b.CID = a.CID 
   AND c.producer != 'Apple'
```

However this returns all customers who bought something other than an Apple product. So I need to be able to compare to other records.

Comment: Homework? Add sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here, the customers who have not purchased Apple products

```
Select cname, Province
From Customer c
Where not exists
   (Select * from Supply s
       join Part p on p.pId = s.pId 
    Where CId = c.CId 
       and p.Producer = 'Apple')
```

and here select the customers who have only purchased Apple products:

```
Select cname, Province
From Customer c
Where exists
   (Select * from Supply s
       join Part p on p.pId = s.pId 
    Where CId = c.CId 
       and p.Producer = 'Apple')
and Not exists   -- <- filter out the customers without an Apple product
   (Select * from Supply n
       join Part nap on nap.pId = n.pId 
    Where CId = c.CId 
       and nap.Producer != 'Apple')
```

Comment: What about this query would I have to change in order to retrieve customers who only purchased apple products?

Comment: Make the  `Not Exists` clause  for products that are 'Apple', an `Exists` clause instead, and add another `Not Exists` clause for products that are *not* apple